# Reformat mysql.log to simple format using awk or sed

Tags: mysql, bash, sed, awk

how to could reformat mysql.log to simple format using awk or sed?

I have a piece of mysql.log:

```
131024 13:17:40     1 Query select * from test_numbers
            1 Query select
  n.id,
  n.name,
  n.value
from test_numbers AS n
limit 0, 50
            1 Query select
  count(*)
FROM test_numbers
            1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:17:50     1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:18:00     1 Query select * from test_numbers
            1 Query select
  n.id,
  n.name,
  n.value
from test_numbers AS n
limit 0, 50
            1 Query select
  count(*)
FROM test_numbers
            1 Query SHOW STATUS
```

The "query" line is spaning across multiple lines.
I want to reformat to this format:

```
131024 13:17:40     1 Query select * from test_numbers
131024 13:17:40     1 Query select  n.id,  n.name,  n.value from test_numbers AS n limit 0, 50
131024 13:17:40     1 Query select  count(*) FROM test_numbers
131024 13:17:40     1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:17:50     1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:18:00     1 Query select * from test_numbers
131024 13:18:00     1 Query select   n.id,  n.name,  n.value from test_numbers AS n limit 0, 50
131024 13:18:00     1 Query select  count(*) FROM test_numbers
131024 13:18:00     1 Query SHOW STATUS
```

When multiple lines of "query" are joined on 1 line.

i tried some scripts, but fails:

```
sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n(^(([0-9]+\t[0-9:]+)|(\t\t[0-9:]+)))/ \1/g' mysql.log
awk '/^(([0-9]+ [0-9:]+)|(\t\t[0-9:]+))/{print "";next}{printf $0}END{print "";}' mysql.log
```

Thanks! i modified some contributions. please, review the answer posted.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` may do what you want.

```
awk '{$1=$1} /Query/ && s {print s;s=""} /^[0-9][0-9]/ {s=$0;f=$1 " " $2} /^[0-9]+ Query/ {s=f " "$0} !/Query/ {s=s " " $0} END {print s}' t
131024 13:17:40 1 Query select * from test_numbers
131024 13:17:40 1 Query select n.id, n.name, n.value from test_numbers AS n limit 0, 50
131024 13:17:40 1 Query select count(*) FROM test_numbers
131024 13:17:40 1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:17:50 1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:18:00 1 Query select * from test_numbers
131024 13:18:00 1 Query select n.id, n.name, n.value from test_numbers AS n limit 0, 50
131024 13:18:00 1 Query select count(*) FROM test_numbers
131024 13:18:00 1 Query SHOW STATUS
```

---

How does it work?

```
awk '
    {
    $1=$1           # reset all spacing to one space
    } 
    /Query/ && s {  # If line has name "Query" and "s" is true (to prevent fist line double"
        print s     # print s
        s=""        # reset s
    }
    /^[0-9][0-9]/ { # if line starts with number
        s=$0        # save line in s
        f=$1 " " $2 # save date time to f
    }
    /^[0-9]+ Query/ {   # if line starts with "number + Query"
        s=f " "$0   # set s date time + line
    }
    !/Query/ {      # If line does not have "Query"
        s=s " " $0  # extend s with line
    }
    END {
    print s}        # print last line
    ' file
```

Comment: i'm trying change a little bit, because there are tabs, no whitespaces. And, "1" its a number much more greater 1, 2... 9999

Comment: The more input data you have, the better it is for us to help. awk does handle space and tabs as Filed Separators if none are set.  `$1=$1` does change all tabs and spaces to single space, so it should be ok. Change `/^1 Query/` to `/^[0-9]+ Query/` to handle number other than `1` Updated my `awk` to handle large numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try following script (it's commented):

Content of `script.awk`:

```
## A line with the timestamp. Get it and remove from the line for further processing.
$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}$/ {
    timestamp = $1 " " $2
    $1 = $2 = ""
}

## A line that points to the beginning of a query. Print the previous one 
## saved in "q" variable and begin to save the current one.
$0 ~ /\<[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]Query\>/ {
    if ( q ) { 
        printf "%s\t%s\n", timestamp, q
        q = ""
    }   
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, "") 
    q = $0
    next
}

## A line that is a continuation of a query. Save its content removing leading
## and trailing spaces.
{
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, "") 
    sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/, "") 
    q = q " " $0
}


## Don't forget the last query when file ends.
END {
    if ( q ) { 
        printf "%s\t%s\n", timestamp, q
        q = ""
    }   
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

That yields:

```
131024 13:17:40 1 Query select * from test_numbers
131024 13:17:40 1 Query select n.id, n.name, n.value from test_numbers AS n limit 0, 50
131024 13:17:40 1 Query select count(*) FROM test_numbers
131024 13:17:50 1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:18:00 1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:18:00 1 Query select * from test_numbers
131024 13:18:00 1 Query select n.id, n.name, n.value from test_numbers AS n limit 0, 50
131024 13:18:00 1 Query select count(*) FROM test_numbers
131024 13:18:00 1 Query SHOW STATUS
```

Comment: Running this on `gnu awk`, you need `--re-interval` since you use this number `{2}`: `awk --re-interval -f script.awk infile`

Comment: @Jotne That's only on older releases of gawk. RE-interval functionality has been the default for a few releases now. If your gawk still needs it, get a new version as you're missing some other great functionality.

Comment: I know, but awk latest Ubuntu 13.10 still does not have this enabled. So its always good to mention due to portability.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/[[:digit:]]+ +Query/ {
    if (rec) print rec

    if ( match($0,/^[[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]:]+ +/) ) {
        ts = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    }
    else {
        sub(/^ +/,ts)
    }

    rec = $0
    next
}

{ sub(/^ +/,""); rec = rec OFS $0 }

END { if (rec) print rec }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
131024 13:17:40     1 Query select * from test_numbers
131024 13:17:40     1 Query select n.id, n.name, n.value from test_numbers AS n limit 0, 50
131024 13:17:40     1 Query select count(*) FROM test_numbers
131024 13:17:40     1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:17:50     1 Query SHOW STATUS
131024 13:18:00     1 Query select * from test_numbers
131024 13:18:00     1 Query select n.id, n.name, n.value from test_numbers AS n limit 0, 50
131024 13:18:00     1 Query select count(*) FROM test_numbers
131024 13:18:00     1 Query SHOW STATUS
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;/^((\S{6} ..:..:..\s*)(\S+ \S+).*\n)\s*\3/{s//\1\2\3/;P;D};/^\S{6} ..:..:...*\n\S{6} ..:..:../{P;D};s/\n\s*/ /;ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all!
I modified the original script proposed by Ed Morton, because mysql.log has tabs and spaces in a messy way. Also, the date field is reformated. Thank u all, guys! Ed, Jotne, Birei.

```
#
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571592/reformat-mysql-log-to-simple-format-using-awk-or-sed/19578281?noredirect=1#19578281
# modified from the original proposed by Ed Morton
#
# Mysql logs some commands: Connect, Quit, Query, Init DB
/[[:digit:]]+ +(Quit|Connect|Query|Init DB)/ {
    if (rec){
     print rec
    }

    $0=cleanTabs($0)

    #replace whitespace to tab in "transaction_id command"
    $0=gensub(/([[:digit:]]+) +(Quit|Connect|Query|Init DB)/, "\\1\t\\2\t", "g")

    if ( match($0,  /^([[:digit:]]+ +[[:digit:]:]+ )/) ) {
    #ts holds "YYMMDD". now, reformat to "YYYY-MM-DD"
    ts = "20" substr($0, 0, 2) "-" substr($0, 3, 2) "-" substr($0, 5, 2) substr($0, 7, 9)
        #sub(/^\t+/,ts OFS)
        sub(/^([[:digit:]]+ +[[:digit:]:]+ )/, ts "\t")
    }
    else {
        sub(/^  /,ts "\t")
    }


    rec = $0
    next
}

{ sub(/^ +/,""); rec = rec OFS $0 }

END { if (rec) print rec }

# convert whitespaces to tabs in the "line"
function cleanTabs(line){
    gsub(/\t/, " ", line)
    return line  
}
```